# Perl fork in recursive subroutine

Tags: perl, recursion, fork

I'm trying to write a recursive script that parses a large directory using forks for better performance. For a simple example, let's say I want to do DFS that runs no more than 10 concurrent forks, something like

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Parallel::ForkManager;

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(10);
&proc_dir("/some/large/directory");
$pm->wait_all_children;

sub proc_dir {
  my $path = shift;
  my(@child_dirlist);

  if(opendir(DIR, $path)) {
    my @d = grep { -d "$path/$_" } readdir(DIR);
    @child_dirlist =  map { "$path/$_" } @d;
    closedir(DIR);
  }

  foreach my $d (@child_dirlist) {
    my $pid = $pm->start and next; #This will fail within child processes
    &proc_dir($d);
    $pm->finish;
  }
}
```

But `Parallel::ForkManager` requires that if you want to fork off more processes from a child process you initialize another `ForkManager`, which kindof defeats the purpose of using one to begin with in this case. I've tried a few other modules/ways of doing this, but haven't had any success both limiting the number of forks to some #/threshold and getting them to work recursivly. Wondering if anyone has managed to solve similar issues or knows a simple workaround.

**Edit**: Please assume I've tested this enough that CPU and I/O load isn't a concern for some small number of forks.

Comment: *"I'm trying to write a recursive script that parses a large directory using forks for better performance."*  Parsing a large directory is an i/o intensive task, anyway, so what gain do you think you could gain by forking?  Did you [profile](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/Devel-NYTProf-5.06/lib/Devel/NYTProf.pm) your script?

Comment: @Kenosis It really isn't that intensive at all (e.g. I've tested doing this on several subdirecotires concurrently without any issue and with considerable performance increases over just parsing the parent)

Comment: @Kenosis: Have you tried it? Most systems cache their file system directories.

Comment: @BroSlow: Have you written a simple sequential version and found it to be too slow? As you would expect, everything is already optimised for finding files by their path so you are unlikely to see much improvement using parallel processes. I would expect your idea to slow things down, if it made any appreciable difference at all. You should never anticipate an optimisation problem: always fix things like that once they surface.

Comment: @Borodin Probably doesn't make that much difference with just traversing the tree, but with doing extra processing like e.g. printing filenames, forking the top level reduces a small 70k file directory from about around 22 seconds to 15 seconds across 100 tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're going to realize the benefits you're looking for with this approach.  You will simply fork off an unlimited number of processes until you overwhelm your machine.  Your goal isn't to use a single instance of PFM, it's to expedite the processing.

To that end, I recommend that you look at the File::Find module. It's a Perl implementation that is related to find, and is most likely what you're looking for.

If I understand your sample code, you're simply looking for directories, so running find2perl will generate a wrapper script for File::Find:

```
find2perl /usr/share/emacs/ -type d
```

Will create the following script (pared down a bit):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Find ();

# for the convenience of &wanted calls, including -eval statements:
use vars qw/*name *dir *prune/;
*name   = *File::Find::name;
*dir    = *File::Find::dir;
*prune  = *File::Find::prune;

# Traverse desired filesystems
File::Find::find({wanted => \&wanted}, '/usr/share/emacs/');
exit;

sub wanted {
    my ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid);

    (($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid) = lstat($_)) &&
    -d _
    && print("$name\n");
}
```

In your wanted() subroutine, you can do whatever you want.  It's shown to be faster than find, and certainly so if you apply logic to each file and do so in your script instead of doing it in subprocesses.

If you want to break the processing out across multiple processes, I recommend iterating over the top-level subdirectories using Parallel::ForkManager.

By the way, I wouldn't worry about instantiating multiple PFM objects.  That's the least of your worries.  Recursively implementing 10 subprocesses per subprocess is much riskier.

One more thing:  if you still want to pursue the recursive PFM approach, you might try running both implementations against one another in a Benchmark harness.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried the `$File::Find` approach before and it is quite a bit faster than one process like above, but slower than several forked running concurrently. In my example I'm basically trying to limit to 10 max, not 10 for each subprocess.

Comment: @BroSlow: "quite a bit faster" and "slower than" say nothing. Please publish your figures, as well as a figure that you need to reach. There are many alternative solutions, depending on your *specific* requirements. Few of them involve parallel processing of directories.

Comment: @Borodin Fair point, will try to run a more concise test tomorrow and upload a graph of a forked-implementation/non-forked/File::Find. Reason I didn't in the question is I came back to this problem after a couple of months of it on the shelf. If `File::Find` proves to be faster, I'll accept the answer then.

Comment: @BroSlow: The question isn't which is faster - `File::Find` will undoubtedly be slower that almost anything else - but whether you really need anything faster and, if so, exactly what directory accesses do you need to accelerate? Please don't just publish random benchmarks - we need to see the *top level* response times - the points where your application is taking so long to respond that you need an ad hoc solution. If all you can do is show that the user sees a 50ms with one technique and a 5ms delay with another then you don't have a problem.

Comment: Seconds differences in small directories would make a considerable difference for ones with 100+ million files. But I will try to re-write this making the other parts of the code multi-threaded since the directory access probably shouldn't be affected. Accepting this answer for now.